# Need help in assigning ASP.NET form variables to embedded C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking to embed C# code into an ASP.NET website.

How do I assign values selected from a drop-down menu on the ASP.NET site form into pre-determined code variables?

My drop down menu text will be text, but I would like to assign them in the code as an integer.
e.g if they selected the colour 'Blue' from the drop down menu, I would like it to assign '2' to my C# variable

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Did the answer below help you, or solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You would bind the drop down list like this, and assign the DataTextField, and the DataValueField

```
var source = new Dictionary<int, string>();
source.Add(0, "Text 1");
source.Add(1, "Text 2");
dropDown.DataSource = source;
dropDown.DataTextField = "Key";
dropDown.DataValueField = "Value";
dropDown.DataBind();
```

You can then access the value, and textx like this;

```
dropDown.SelectedItem.Value
dropDown.SelectedItem.Text
```

Answer (score -3):

If dropdawn name is x then
Assign DropDawn Value to a variable Y 
Y=deopdawn.selecteditem.value

```
int y=0;
y=dropdawl.SelectedIten.value;
```